# Replace Values in Range

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I've tried to do this replacement in two different ways (first attempt commented below), but it ends up replacing everything on the sheet, instead:

```
Sub NoNullSaveCSV()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim find1 As Variant
    Dim rplc1 As Variant
    Dim find2 As Variant
    Dim rplc2 As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range

    Application.Workbooks.Add xlWBATWorksheet
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set WS = ActiveSheet

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PedidosTratados")
        .Range("A3:DW1000").Copy
        WS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    WS.Range("A1").Value = "FilterCol"
    WS.Columns.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""
    WS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    WS.AutoFilterMode = False

    ReplaceCount = ReplaceCount + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WS.Cells, "*" & fnd1 & "*")
    '+ Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WS.Cells, "*" & fnd2 & "*")

    fnd1 = "7.9000"
    rplc1 = "7.900"
    fnd2 = "9.9000"
    rplc2 = "9.900"

    With WS
        .Range("AT2:DW1000").Replace fnd1, rplc1
        .Range("AT2:DW1000").Replace fnd2, rplc2

        '.Cells.Replace what:=fnd1, Replacement:=rplc1, _
        'LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, _
        'SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        '.Cells.Replace what:=fnd2, Replacement:=rplc2, _
        'LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, _
        'SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With

        WB.SaveAs fileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Pedidos.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
        WB.Close False

MsgBox "Após a pesquisa, foram feitas " & ReplaceCount & " substituições."

End Sub
```

Could you anyone tell me why this is not restraining replacement to the specified range?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't use the `Range.Replace` method sorry, but having a quick look at the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) I can see you are only using the first 2 parameters which are for *What* and *Replacement*. You might want to use the *LookAt* parameter also?

Comment: Hello @SamuelEverson! I tried that as well, but I couldn't have it replace what was within the range only.

Comment: After further inspection I was wrong - haha! Sorry about that.

Comment: `ws.cells` means   every cell in the sheet.  `.Range("AT2:DW1000")` means specific range.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I'd tried it both ways, but I see it now. Still a beginner here, so pardon my concept/logic misses.

Comment: @Dy.Lee, I also tried replacing .cells with .Range("AT2:DW1000").replace, but it didn't work. It changed everything in the sheet.